# Копирующие операции класса с полем некопируемого типа

Tags: c++, классы, c++11, оператор-присваивания, конструктор-копирования

Предположим, поле класса имеет тип `std::unique_ptr<...>`. Имя поля `m_ptr`. Корректно ли будет реализовать к-р копирования такого класса, например, так:

```
Class(const Class& c) : ptr_m(std::make_unique<...>(*(c.m_ptr))) {}
```

А оператор копирующего присваивания так:

```
Class& operator= (const Class& c) 
{
    m_ptr.reset(std::make_unique<...>(*(c.m_ptr))); 
    return *this;
}
```

Не противоречит ли это идеологии `std::unique_ptr`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне это представляется хаком, который вполне осуществим на практике (при копируемом объекте внутри `unique_ptr`), но вот права на это осуществление он не имеет :)

**IMHO**

Перемещающее копирование - да, но обычное копирование? По-моему, это нарушает сам принцип, ради которого создан `unique_ptr` - уникальное владение ресурсом. А тут получается размножение этого ресурса. Формально - да, каждый объект владеет своим ресурсом, но вот семантика, как мне кажется, теряется.

С другой стороны, если ресурс некопируемый - то и способ этот не сработает.

Вот примерно такое мнение - технически возможно, идеологически - не стоит. Вернее, так - можно, с пониманием того, что и зачем делается. Просто ну вот зачем тогда вообще `unique_ptr`?

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Answer (score 4):

`std::make_unique` получает аргументы, с которыми функция [попытается сконструировать](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/04c4a9200b22af5ab5d5f1107d5c538b37eddcb6/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/unique_ptr.h#L831) ресурс в куче, а так как там стоит разыменование указателя, то вызывается конструктор копирования типа ресурса. Таким образом два `std::unique_ptr` будут ссылаться **на разные объекты**.

*Однако, тип ресурса сам должен поддерживать копирование.*

> Не противоречит ли это идеологии std::unique_ptr?

К ошибке это не приведет, если умышленно не получать сырой указатель (у `std::unique_ptr` нет конструктора копирования, только перемещение, компилятор спасёт от `std::unique_ptr p1( p2 )`). Однако, если логика вашей программы предполагает совместное пользование ресурсом, то `std::shared_ptr` подойдет лучше.

Answer (score 0):

Копируется же не указатель, а его содержимое, значит все нормально.